# Dummy array value not populating after function call

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to create dropdown which populate state based on country,city based on city but initially when page loads it contains previously pulled data from array.While trying to call GetSelectedCountry and GetSelectedState function not   working because of mydata which include in ng-model and dummy array value in dropdown initialy not showing when page loads.Following is the my dummy code.

```
<head>
    <!--ajax library-->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //angular module code
        angular
        .module('myApp', [])
        .run(function($rootScope) {
                $rootScope.title = 'myTest Page';
            })
        .controller('testController', ['$scope',
                function($scope) {
                    //dummy array data

                    $scope.mydata = [

                        { "cID": 1014,"country": "USA","state" :"California"}
                    ];   

                    //country json to get selected state and city based on country
                    $scope.countries = {

                        'USA': {
                            'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
                            'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
                            'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
                        },
                        'Australia': {
                            'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
                            'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
                        }
                    };
                    $scope.GetSelectedCountry = function() {
                        $scope.strCountry = $scope.country;
                    };
                    $scope.GetSelectedState = function() {
                        $scope.strState = $scope.state;
                    };
                }
            ])</script></head>
<!--HTML Code-->
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="testController">   <label for="country">Country
            *</label>   <select id="country" name="country" ng-model="mydata .country" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries"
        ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()">
            <option value=''>Select</option></select>   <label for="state">State *</label>   <select id="state"
        ng-disabled="!country" name="state" ng-model="mydata.state"
        ng-options="state for (state,city) in country"
        ng-change="GetSelectedState()">
            <option value=''>Select</option></select>   <label for="city">City *</label>   <select id="city" ng-disabled="!country
        || !state" ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in state">
            <option value=''>Select</option>

        </select>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using mydata.country and mydata.state in ng-model so in script you can access those by

```
  $scope.GetSelectedCountry = function() {
                    $scope.strCountry = $scope.mydata.country;
                };
                $scope.GetSelectedState = function() {
                    $scope.strState = $scope.mydata.state;
                };
```

Else just change the ng-model name in your html for country and state like

```
<select id="country" name="country" ng-model="country" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries"
        ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()">
            <option value=''>Select</option></select>   <label for="state">State *</label>   
<select id="state" ng-disabled="!country" name="state" ng-model="state" ng-options="state for (state,city) in country"
```

Attaching a plunker that works

https://plnkr.co/edit/zUyL9aGSWt9hysH4cjnT?p=preview

Comment: I already got it this ,I was actually asking you to initially how to populate $scope.mydata array  data in dropdown such as country USA and state california after he able to change country and state